Is there room for finding a more efficient hybrid optimization problem, in the context of optimization algorithms for MLE?
Recently finished my statistical modelling class, but it only briefly touched on Maximum Likelihood Estimates and I thought it was an interesting topic, so I decided to go deeper in my own time. I found how you exactly find the estimates, and I encountered methods like Gradient Descent and Newton's Method, each with their own strengths and weaknesses.
From my limited understanding, hybrid methods seem like an area where the possibilities are endless. For example, batch gradient descent converging slower than stochastic gradient descent because it doesn't calculate in batches but in single points, however SGD might take longer to implement and etc... (Although mini-batch SGD also exists, which I find hilarious and interesting how it keeps on taking parts from other methods and so on).
I'm trying to find a project idea which I can present to my professor, and I am not asking for that idea from you but rather, am I right to think there is a hybrid method I could tweak for some specific objective? Or is this way above my level and I would be seen as a pretentious unknowing 2nd year Maths student approaching my professor with this?
